# How to getCurrentPosition via navigator.geolocation in Electron app?

Tags: javascript, html, electron

When I try to get the current position

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handleCoordinates, handleError, {timeout:10000})
```

it returns

> "Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 400."

Can somebody suggest any possible ways?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should configure correct google api key to request google related services in chromium.

https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/environment-variables.md#google_api_key

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/9420

Comment: I set process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY in main process file, now it's working. Thanks!

Comment: how i set process

Comment: Just be sure that you have **ENABLED** [Geolocation API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/geolocation.googleapis.com) for your project. If not enabled, your api key will be ignored for Geolocation API calls.

Answer (score 0):

Initializing Google Api Key In Main JS file :

```
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  process.env.GOOGLE_API_KEY = 'AI.....'
  createWindow()

  app.on('activate', () => {
    if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
      createWindow()
    }
  })
})
```

and Calling below method in preload js :

```
 if (navigator.geolocation) {
    console.log('with in if block');
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      console.log("Latitude : " + position.coords.latitude);
    } ,(err ) =>{
      console.log("getting error : " + err.message);
    } , {timeout:10000})

  } else { 
    console.log('with in else block');
  }

  //enter code here: "User has not allowed access to system location."
```