# Geolocation on electron js

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, geolocation, electron

When trying to use geolocation in an electron app, returns the following message:

> Network location provider at 'https://www.googleapis.com/' : Returned error code 400.

I'm using [geolocation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolocation) library. Searching google, I found that this may be a chromium issue, but it has no solution.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var geolocation = require('geolocation');
   geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(err, position){
      if (err) throw err
        console.log(position);
      });
});
```

Comment: Can you provide you code and the issue so we have more context?

Comment: error 400 means `400 Bad Request Error` so you've to adjust your request and post your code to get help with it. Please edit your question to include it instead of posting it as comment. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need this package. Read this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition and this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955815/how-to-getcurrentposition-via-navigator-geolocation-in-electron-app